# How to make nodemailer with SMTP work?

Tags: node.js, express, gmail, nodemailer

I've already lowered my gmail account's security here:
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

I've tried to send mail with, and without smtp, but always get some kind of error.
Error: invalid login: 535.5.....
I checked my "user", and "from" parameters are the same. Here's a bit of my code. I'm working on localhost. May it be the problem?

```
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var smtpTransport = require("nodemailer-smtp-transport");

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
        user: "seratothdevelop@gmail.com", // my mail
        pass: "*********"
    }
 }));

       console.log('SMTP Configured');

  var message = "<b>Kedves Felhasználó!</b>"+
                "<p>Sikeresen feliratkoztál a Kutyapplikáció hírlevelére, ahonnan friss információkkal látunk el hétről-hétre.</p>"+
                "<br><p>Üdvözlettel, </p><p><i>sethdevelop</i></p>";

    var mailOptions = {
    from: "seratothdevelop@gmail.com", // sender address
    to: request.body.subscribeduser, // list of receivers
    subject: "Kutyapp feliratkozás", // Subject line
    html: message // You can choose to send an HTML body instead
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
     if(error){
        console.log(error);
     }else{
        console.log('Üzenet elküldve: ' + info.response);
    }
      transporter.close();
    });
```

Comment: It really looks like your credentials are not correct

Comment: I believe the service string is case sensitive, use `service: 'Gmail',` ...